# Pausing a video inside a pure css modal when closing, using an external videoplayer source

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog, html5-video, pause

I am currently using an external video player to put different videos into modals using an iframe, called by a PHP function (see code below). The videoplayer is the onelineplayer from here: https://onelineplayer.com/

For the modals I am currently using the css modal solution from here:
https://github.com/drublic/css-modal/

The videos load fine, everything runs smoothly, the one hurdle I can't overcome yet is: I want to pause or stop the video once the modal closes, either by clicking a close button or clicking outside of the modal area. How can I do that?

This is how it looks:
https://vimeo.com/339937444

I have tried various solutions here on StackOverflow and throughout other websites but have not found a working solution for my problem. Right now I am sitting on this code, trying to get the onelineplayer to pause:

```
var vid = document.getElementsByClassName('oneline');
$('#modal-close').click(function(){
vid.pause();
});

var $video = $(".oneline")[0];
$video.autoplay = false;

$(".modal-close").click(function() {
$video.pause();
$video.currentTime = 0;
});
```

**This is the HTML of the Modal Window:**

```
 <section class="modal--show modal-main" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>"     
  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="<?php echo $postid; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-inner">
    <header id="modal-label">
    </header>

    <div class="modal-content">
      <?php echo wp_show_posts_videolink(); ?>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a href="#!" class="modal-close" id="modal-close" title="Close this modal" 
  data-close="Close" data-dismiss="modal" >
</a>
</section>
```

This is the (shorted) output of the wp_show_posts_videolink(); from above function displaying the whole onelineplayer iframe instead of  once the modal is opened:

```
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px;" src="https://onelineplayer.com/player.html?autoplay=false&amp;loop=false&amp;autopause=true&amp;muted=true&amp;url=https://vimeo.com/189904045&amp;poster=null&amp;time=true&amp;progressBar=true&amp;playButton=true&amp;overlay=true&amp;muteButton=true&amp;fullscreenButton=true&amp;style=light&amp;logo=false&amp;quality=720p" frameborder="0"></iframe>
#document
<html>
<head>

  <meta property="og:url" content="https://onelineplayer.com">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://onelineplayer.com/common/images/ol-og-screen.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
  <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA119543203-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-119543203-1');
  </script>
</head>
<body class="oneline-player">
  <div class="oneline-wrap oneline-ready oneline-paused">
    <video class="oneline" preload="metadata" playsinline="" 
    src="https://gcs.vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1559553745~acl=%2A%2F633644040.mp4%2A~hmac=feeca06925acd17aa4dfa5ee1221dd58a20d016081d5f20667e1a76ba6c59ff0/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/2980/7/189904045/633644040.mp4" poster="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/600730411"></video>
    <script src="player.js"></script>
    <script>
      init()
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

What matters to me is that the video inside the oneline-wrap class gets paused once the modal closes. I tried forcing a oneline-paused class into it when closed but that didn't work. Iam really not knowledgeable enough to get a good grip on the problem, maybe some of you can point me in the right direction of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is, that you're trying to access the contents of the onelineplayer.com iFrame with JavaScript code that lives outside of the iFrame. It won't let you do that because of same origin policy, which prevents JavaScript accessing content across domains.

Technically there are ways to communicate with a cross-domain iFrame, but the other side (in your case onelineplayer.com) needs to implement/allow it from their side.

Are all your videos from vimeo? Any specific reason you use onelineplayer.com and not a more "native" integration of vimeo?

Comment: Thanks for the input! Onelineplayer was the only one I could get working inside a modal that calls a wordpress function. It also lets me use video files from Google Drive and Dropbox which I cannot do with other code (so far). Displaying video directly from services like Google Drive is pretty important for what I am trying to do. I'll try finding a native player and test it out. There got to be similar solutions somewhere.

Edit: And I forgot, the way video files are inserted is controlled by people who don't know a lot about wordpress, so the player is very easy to use for others.

Comment: @festgebaeck OK, I see the reason for using onelineplayer. I assume you configure the embed urls with `&autopause=1`? I couldn't find any information on what this actually is supposed to do, but maybe it's worth trying out. Another approach could be to store the iframe src url in a data attribute like `data-src` then dynamically set and remove it via JavaScript when the modal is opened / closed, that would probably "stop" (although not pause) the video...

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am just getting around to trying it out and actually found another plugin that lets me use dropbox videos inside a data-src attribute, so I don't have to hack my way through the iframe and external code. So I abandoned the oneline player for now and going with another similar jquery plugin (modal-video.js). Thanks for the push in the right direction!